# How to initialize variable within block?

Tags: java, gwt

Issue with used variable in inner loop.

```
Timer innerTimer = new Timer() {         
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for(final Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
          if(stopTimer) {
            this.cancel();
            innerTimer = null; // It shows "Cannot refer to a non-final variable innerTimer inside an inner class defined in a different method"
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

If I changed The above code as :

```
    final Timer innerTimer = new Timer() {         
      @Override
      public void run() {
        for(final Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
          if(stopTimer) {
            this.cancel();
            innerTimer = null; // "The final local variable innerTimer cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

I am using this timer from GWT (`com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer`).

How to intialized variable in inner loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?. `innerTimer = null;` is not *initializing*. It is changing the reference to point to `null`.

Comment: You are right I want to change the reference.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Actually problem is that first I stop the timer. And when I restart the timer, timer will start with the old values. That is the problem.

Comment: "timer start using old values" what do you mean my this?

Comment: @Ajax Timer start with the previous data which I have already canceled before.

Comment: You mean it start using list of old rectangles again to draw, right?

Comment: @Ajax No. I used this timer for create a animation. suppose animation - 1 playing  in the mean time I cancel it so timer cancel the execution. And if I start the animation - 2 the timer working with two animation namely animation - 1 and animation - 2.

Comment: As per my understanding you have 2 implementation(animation - 1 & 2) which you want run alternately with single timer. In this case wrapping up timer mentioned by @Manos with your custom methods is solution for you. If you wish, I can put some sample code as well.

Comment: @Ajax If you have some example then please put the example here.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the `Timer` object. E.g.

```
public class TimerWrap {

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void cancel() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
final TimerWrap innerTimer = new TimerWrap() {
    public void run() {
        for (final Rectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
            if (stopTimer) {
                this.cancel();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `AtomicReference`:

```
final AtomicReference<Timer> innerTimer = new AtomicReference<>();
innerTimer.set(
  new Timer() {
    @Override public void run() {
      innerTimer.set(null);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply but I can not used in this way because I used timer in GWT.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty please put pertinent details like that in the question. This answer is appropriate for what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can not reasign a final object. also, in your example, nulling your innerTimer object is not neccesary at all.

Accessing variables in an inner class needs them to be final to assure that they are not changed outside of your innerclass.

As pointed out before, you can use a `AtomicReference` or an `ObjectProperty`. (Altough I dont see a reason for that in your example)

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to emulate `AtomicReference` or create a class to hold your variable and encapsulate it.

Emulation can be done like that: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html (Overriding one package implementation with another).
But you will need the source for `AtomicReference`, which is part of the JDK.
And internally it heavily relies on `Unsafe` functions from the JDK core, which are not supported by GWT.

So finally you might end up creating a simple wrapper class like Manos Nikolaidis proposed.